# Swift uipageviewcontroller in uipageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm looking for at solution where I have one `uipageviewcontroller` embedded in another `uipageviewcontroller` so when I try to swipe the last `viewcontroller` in the inner `uipageviewcontroller` then it changes the parent `uipageviewcontroller`.

I'm not quite sure if the solution is to have this embedded uipageviewcontroller og if there is another solution that is better.

Any good ideas how to accomplish this functionality?

Comment: better to use scrollview inside pagecontroller .

Comment: I not sure how to accomplish what I am looking for with the scrollview? I have a structure where I have parent views that each contains x subviews. When I start swiping the subviews in the first parentview changes. When I get to the end of the subviews of the first parentview then the swipe function grabs the parentview and swipes to the next parentview.

Comment: you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that the uipageviewcontroller actually handles it if you just include uipageviewcontrollers in eachother so no need for extra code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795151/nested-uipageviewcontroller-transition is this what you wanted to achieve ?